# How to display an array of objects after I manipulated it

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a leaderboard for a generic game page with React.

1. The data for my leaderboard is imported with useState, it's an Array of Objects.
2. Then It's passed down to its child component through its props.
3. In the component I want to order the objects in the imported array, and then display them.

This is my code:

```
    import React,{useState,useEffect} from "react";
import StartArea from "./StartArea"

const LeaderBoard = (props) => {
const leaderboard = props.leaderList;

console.log(leaderboard)
console.log(props)

const Ranking  = () => {
  var unrankedList = leaderboard   
  var rankedList = []
   // using this for loop to sort the leaderList 
  for (let i=0;i<unrankedList.length;i++){
    // reduce the array of object to find and push the highest score.
    let highestRank = unrankedList.reduce((acc, stats) => acc && acc.Sticks / acc.Turns > stats.Sticks / stats.Turns ? acc : stats, null);
    rankedList.push(highestRank)
    // remove the highest rank of this iteration.
    unrankedList.splice(unrankedList.indexOf(highestRank),unrankedList.indexOf(highestRank)+1)
    // repeat itereration by decreasing itereration counter
    i--
  ;}
  // array to return:
  console.log(rankedList)

  return( <table>
    {rankedList.map((item,t)=>(
      <tr className="playerStats">
      <th className="rankIcon">{t+1}</th>
      <th className="playerName">{item.Name}</th>
      <th className="playerSticks">{item.Sticks}</th>
      <th className="playerTurns">{item.Turns}</th>
      <th className="playerTime">{item.Time}</th>
      <th className="playerScore" >{parseFloat(item.Sticks/item.Turns).toFixed(1)}</th>
      </tr>)
      )}</table>);
}

 
    
  
    return(
    <React.Fragment>
    <div id="leaderBoard">
      <div id="leaderboardFrame">
      <h2><i className="fas fa-trophy"></i> Leaderboard</h2>
      <table>
      <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th>Player</th>
      <th>Sticks</th>
      <th>Turns</th>
      <th>Time</th>
      <th className="playerScore">Score</th>
      </tr>
    
      <Ranking/>
      </table>
      
      <p>Time/Sticks=Score</p>
      </div>
      <StartArea/>
    </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}

 export default LeaderBoard
```

Now my problem is that it does not display the rankedList.map part even though my console.log(rankedList) shows exactly the Array as I want it. I just cannot display it correctly

Answer (score 0):

(would be mess as a comment)
I believe it would be:

```
return( <table>
  {rankedList.map((item,t)=>(
    <tr className="playerStats">
    <th className="rankIcon">{t+1}</th>
    <th className="playerName">{item.Name}</th>
    <th className="playerSticks">{item.Sticks}</th>
    <th className="playerTurns">{item.Turns}</th>
    <th className="playerTime">{item.Time}</th>
    <th className="playerScore" >{parseFloat(item.Sticks/item.Turns).toFixed(1)}</th>
    </tr>)
    )}</table>);
```

EDIT: Working Sample.

components/ranking.js

```
import React from "react";

const Ranking = (props) => {
    var unrankedList = props.leaderList;
    var rankedList = []
    // using this for loop to sort the leaderList
    for (let i=0;i<unrankedList.length;i++){
        // reduce the array of object to find and push the highest score.
        let highestRank = unrankedList.reduce((acc, stats) => acc && acc.Sticks / acc.Turns > stats.Sticks / stats.Turns ? acc : stats, null);
        rankedList.push(highestRank)
        // remove the highest rank of this iteration.
        unrankedList.splice(unrankedList.indexOf(highestRank),unrankedList.indexOf(highestRank)+1)
        // repeat itereration by decreasing itereration counter
        i--
        ;}
    // array to return:
    console.log(rankedList)

    return( <table><tbody>
        {rankedList.map((item,t)=>(
            <tr key={item.Name} className="playerStats">
                <th className="rankIcon">{t+1}</th>
                <th className="playerName">{item.Name}</th>
                <th className="playerSticks">{item.Sticks}</th>
                <th className="playerTurns">{item.Turns}</th>
                <th className="playerTime">{item.Time}</th>
                <th className="playerScore" >{parseFloat(item.Sticks/item.Turns).toFixed(1)}</th>
            </tr>)
        )}</tbody></table>);
}
export default Ranking
```

index.js

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Ranking from "./components/ranking";

const leaders = [
    {
        Name: "Player 1",
        Sticks: 5,
        Turns: 2,
        Time: 40,
    },
    {
        Name: "Player 2",
        Sticks: 15,
        Turns: 22,
        Time: 10,
    },
];
ReactDOM.render(
  <Ranking leaderList={leaders}/>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: This solution does not work because the rankedList Array is not created if my ranking function was not called.

Comment: You would be calling it when you do <Ranking />, no?

Comment: I changed it to be called like this now, but it still doesnt display it (but I can still see that its called, yes) 
I update my code preview to show what my whole component looks like

Comment: BTW, probably you would want to put your array in a state.

Comment: Can you be a little bit more specific? which array should I put in a state? the rankedList?

Comment: Yes. Without a state you wouldn't see anything.

Comment: So I should pass my rankedList array to a state and then display the state?
But how can I do that? in the render part of my component is my ranking function component called now, but if I try to set a state inside of my ranking function then i get the error :"
Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate"

Comment: Sorry about state, what was I thinking I don't know. Adding a full sample that does work (ignore my values, I don't even know what Sticks, Turns ... would look like in fact).